# VBA IE control, click button without ID

Tags: vba

HTML Source

```
<TD title=Action class=text-button noWrap itemID="emx1330297690134.9116">Action
<IMG border=0 src="http://gpdm.lge.com/enovia/common/images/utilMenuArrow.gif" align=absMiddle></TD>
```

how to click the button without id?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set iE_1 = objShell.Windows(j) ' -> No matter j
Set tags_td = iE_1.document.getElementsByTagName("td")

For Each tagx In tags_td
    If tagx.innerText = "Action" Then
        tagx.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

(If tagx.innerText = "Action" Then) -> I have no idea Why Action does not recognized.

Anyother solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you add `Debug.Print tagx.innerText` inside the loop what output do you get?

Comment: iE_1.document.querySelector("td[title=Action]").click

Comment: Lots of things prints. I guess the 'Action' is included in tagx.innerText

Comment: Maybe `If tagx.innerText Like "Action*" Then` could do it

Comment: Tim, Thanks. it does work well. what is difference of "=" between  "Like" ? Like is more powerful ?

Comment: If you use `=` then it has to match exactly - an extra space on the end will mean no match.  Using `Like` with a wildcard gives some flexibility.